# Prevent Rstudio from displaying plots in the source panel

Tags: r, rstudio

Hi this only started happening in Version 1.0.136.  When I have a markdown file the plots are displayed in the source panel.

````
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

for example when execute by running the chunk the plot is displayed on source panel instead of the regular plot panel, like so.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWqn1.png

I notice that this is only when I'm using markdown and only for the newer version.  Is there anyway I can disable this so that the graphs are display in the usual plot panel? thanks!

Comment: Go to your "Global Option" -> Rmarkdown -> Show Output preview in "View Panel"

Comment: thank Hao, that did not do it, at least for interactive mode.  I finally found a solution, which is I answered below and here is a screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/Kiq6o2q.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.  This is a new feature in notebook. To get rid of this, on the source panel, there is a little setting icon, choose that and select Chunkoutput to console. Here is a screenshot:

[image]